# Socket.io get user session variables

Tags: node.js, session, socket.io

I'm using socket.io and I want to know how can I get all user variables inside my express session. I'm using passport js for the authentication.

I can get all variable if I pass my req.user to the view and get it inside an hiddenfield in my .ejs view.

```
app.get('/node', function(req, res){
    res.render('pages/index', {
        user : req.user
    });
});
```

And inside my view I can do that :

```
<input type="hidden" value="<%= user.local.email %>"/>
```

But I don't like this way and it's possible to get the req variable inside socket.io ?

I tried this :

```
var io = require("socket.io")(http)
    .use(function(socket, next){
        // Wrap the express middleware
        sessionMiddleware(socket.request, {}, next);
    })
    .on("connection", function(socket){
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        console.log(socket.request.session);
        });
    });
```

But inside my console.log `console.log(socket.request.session);` I don't have the information of the user I just have the session user id.

```
Session {
  cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true },
  flash: {},
  passport: { user: '579cc16c856d6feb35af584f' } }
```

How can I get all the information like inside the req.user variable ?

Comment: As you've seen, the cookie contains the session ID.  You need to use that to look up the actual session in the session store.  Here's a complete explanation of how to use passport and socket.io together:https://www.codementor.io/tips/0217388244/sharing-passport-js-sessions-with-both-express-and-socket-io

Comment: There is no other ways that passport.socketio ? Because I'll use socket io just for notification / chat and this will break my server.js configuration. The ID inside my console.log isn't the session ID but the user ID in mongodb

Comment: You could insert whatever you want in the cookie when you get successful authentication and then that should be there for the socket.io cookie too, but you do have to make sure you preserve your auth security.  Why does the recommended solution in that article break your server configuraiton?

Comment: I set custom variable inside the passport.serializeUser function and it works without passportsocketio